# how to implement addShowHideListener inside fragment in android

Tags: android

I have fragement inside activity .if I have click fragment view have to show or hide another fragment is it possible? if it is can anybody tell how to do ?.I have done but it show compilation error.this below is textview inside fragment

fm=getFragmentManager();
          addShowHideListener(layout.findViewById(R.id.txtIhaveAnIdea).getId(),fm.findFragmentById(R.id.subFrag));

thanks